# django jeditable datatables multiple inputs same td

Tags: jquery, django, datatables, jeditable

I'm working on django project, and I have successfully integrated it with the jQuery datatables display (this is a general example, my code is slightly longer and a lot more specific, but this is the important parts):

template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/employee_table/"
    } );
} );

</script>


<table id='example'>
    <thead>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>state</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>registration date</th>
        <th>projects</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

serverside:

```
def main_view(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

def datatables_view(request):
    start = request.GET['iDisplayStart']
    length = request.GET['iDisplayLength']

    query = Employee.objects.all()

    if request.GET.has_key('sSearch'):
        # filtering...


    query = query[start:start+length]
    response = ["aaData": [(q.name, q.state, q.email_disp(), q.regdate_disp(), q.projects_disp()) for q in query]]

    # return serialized data
```

This works without a hitch. Now I want to allow my users to edit the data in-place. The jEditable plugin works, but there are a few problems with it:

- email_disp is a function that colors the email according to the content (for example, it adds html tags around the field so if it's gmail the text color is green). When I want to edit this with jEditable, it also shows me the tags, which is not so good.
- regdate_disp is a function that simply outputs the date and time of registration in a specific way. However, when people edit this td I'd like them to see two different inputs - one for date (that would be a jQuery datepicker) and one for time (just a regulat text field).
- Every employee has several projects (it's a ManyToMany relationship), and the projects_disp function does something like: return ', '.join(Employee.projects.all()). However, when editing this field, I think the best display would be a dropdown checklist.

As you can see, the simple functionality of jEditable doesn't really help me. The ideal way that I think of solving this is to have a button next to each row of the table, that when clicked, will send the server this row, and would get back an array (like aaData) of custom-made inputs to replace each td. The button would change to a save icon and when clicked a second time would recollect the data.

However, I'm really not very good with javascript and I don't know how to do any of that. Any help or full on examples would be much appreciated (including how to integrate the solution with datatables without breaking anything).

Comment: Your last paragraph makes me think that you want someone to do it for you. That's not how it works here. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: No no, I'm just really unexperienced with js and I'd like some direction on how it should be used here. I have the basic idea of what needs to be done but I'm not sure where to start